# Conflicts in deleting row in UITableView with KVO

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a "recents" section in my `UITableView`. The number of rows here is determined by `MIN(10, self.itemCollection.count)` so that the section is either 10, or the total number of items in the collection.

I'm using the following code in my KVO method `observeValueForKeyPath`:

```
NSKeyValueChange kindOfChange = [change[NSKeyValueChangeKindKey] unsignedIntegerValue];
if (kindOfChange == NSKeyValueChangeRemoval) {
    NSIndexSet *indexSetOfChanges = change[NSKeyValueChangeIndexesKey];
    NSMutableArray *indexPathsThatChanged = [NSMutableArray new];
    [indexSetOfChanges enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:idx inSection:1];
        [indexPathsThatChanged addObject:newIndexPath];
    }];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsThatChanged withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

I get the error `Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (10) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)`.

I have tried inserting an `NSIndexPath` at the last row as well (since I'm removing one) but get the error `attempt to insert row 10 into section 1, but there are only 10 rows in section 1 after the update`.

Aren't the delegate methods called right after this? They are the first 10 items from the user's collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error indicates that the operations you're performing on the table (`deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` in your posted code) are not consistent with the value that is returned by your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method implementation.  Ultimately that message is telling you "Last time I called `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` for section 1, it said there were 10 items.  Now you've said you deleted 1 item, but `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` still returns 10."

To fix this issue, you must make `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` behave in a manner consistent with your calls to methods that tell the table view you've changed the number of objects.

**Original Answer**

The line:

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathsThatChanged] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Is wrapping your `indexPathsThatChanged` array in another array.  This is probably not what you want, as the method expects an array of `NSIndexPath` instances, not an array of an array of `NSIndexPath` instances.  You should change it to:

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsThatChanged withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that in my question...that popped up at the end of my troubleshooting which is not my original issue.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I want the user to see that the row is "deleting", but most of the time the recents section will always be 10 (let's assume that for now). So I delete a row, then insert an index path at "row 10" so the whole table shifts. This should still equate to 10 rows...in line with what the `numberOfRowsInSection` is returning. I even tried for example removing row 3, looping rows 4-10 to move them up, then adding a row at 10. Still assertion errors. I'm not sure what else to do in numberOfRows...I always want it to be 10 rows.

Comment: No where in your code do you insert a row.  You would have to do this between your calls to `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` on `tableView` in order for things to be consistent.  As soon as you call `endUpdates` the table view will call the delegate methods to determine the number of rows.  If you added the row elsewhere, that would cause the second error in your question.

Comment: In my question I mention I also tried inserting a row, indeed it was between `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`.

Comment: I suggest you put breakpoints on all the lines where you insert or delete rows, and a breakpoint in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` so you can track down where it's being inconsistent.  That is what the errors you refer to indicate.  Given you haven't posted complete code, it's hard to give you more specific advice.

Comment: My ultimate issue was that i was inserting the `NSIndexPath` at row 10, while it should be row 9 (#10). The `numberOf...` methods are confusing me with the actual indexes.